# Output accented characters for use with latex

Tags: r, latex

I'm trying to use `R` to create the content of a tex file. The content contains many accented letters and I not able to correctly write them to a tex file.

Here is a short minimal example of what I would like to perform:

I have a file `texinput.tex`, which already exists and is encoded as UTF8 without BOM. When I manually write `é` in Notepad++ and save this file, it compiles correctly in `LaTex` and the output is as expected.

Then I tried to do this in `R`:

```
str.to.write <- "é"
cat(str.to.write, file = "tex_list.tex", append=TRUE)
```

As a result, the encoded character `xe9` appears in the tex file. `LaTex` throws this error when trying to compile:

```
! File ended while scanning use of \UTFviii@three@octets.<inserted text>\par \include{texinput}
```

I then tried all of the following things before the cat command:

```
Encoding(str.to.write) <- "latin1"
```

-> same output error as above

---

```
str.to.write <- enc2utf8(str.to.write)
```

-> same output and error as above

---

```
Encoding(str.to.write) <- "UTF-8"
```

-> this appears in the tex file: `\xe9`. `LaTex` throws this error: `! Undefined control sequence. \xe`

---

```
Encoding(str.to.write) <- "bytes"
```

-> this appears in the tex file: `\\xe9`. `LaTex` compiles without error and the output is `xe9`

---

I know that I could replace `é` by `\'{e}`, but I would like to have an automatic method, because the real content is very long and contains words from 3 different  Latin languages, so it has lots of different accented characters.

However, I would also be happy about a function to automatically sanitize the R output to be used with Latex. I tried using `xtable` and `sanitize.text.function`, but it appears that it doesn't accept character vectors as input.

Comment: You could also use `gsub` to replace these special characters with appropriate character strings to use in LaTeX, e.g., `gsub("è","\\\\`{e}",x)`. This can be automatized and put into a function as long as you're willing to define the replacement rules once per symbol.

Comment: This would have been my Plan B. However, I found a way to do it without having to define all the rules manually (see my answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After quite a bit of searching and trial-and-error, I found something that worked for me:

```
# create output function
writeTex <- function(x) {write.table(x, "tex_list.tex", 
                                     append = TRUE, row.names = FALSE, 
                                     col.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE,
                                     fileEncoding = "UTF-8")}
writeTex("é")
```

Output is as expected (`é`), and it compiles perfectly well in LaTex.

Answer (score 0):

Use [TIPA](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb17-2/tb51rei.pdf) for processing International
Phonetic Alphabet (IPA) symbols in Latex. It has become standard in the linguistics field.